# why command prompt take less time to run the python program as compare to python IDLE?

Tags: python, performance, time

I want to check the running time of my program by using this.

```
start_time = time.time()
print(time.time() - start_time)
```

but the result was surprising in cmd it gives time of 1.2 sec but in python IDLE time is 5.12 sec.

why it is so?

Comment: I would suggest use [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) instead of time. And yes, differently prepared/executed python environments matter.

Answer (score 1):

Python IDLE is some kind of a wrapper around python environment. Let's say, it's like python.exe+wrapper. IDLE has GUI, buttons, text field,etc. So, it has to handle Python environment and the GUI at once. IDLE is a full Windows program. It's OK that it's faster to run pure python.exe than python.exe and all the stuff in IDLE.